# For whatever reason, PHP 7.4.4 does not want to target the path php_mysqli.dll (Windows 10 Server edition)

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7.4

I managed to set up a PHP server by watching several tutorials on the subject. I want to get into storing data into PHPMyAdmin. Everything is good except one. PHP does not want to enable mysqli.dll which is required to run PHPMyAdmin. So far, I have this PHP code for the file php.ini.

```
[PHP]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
;
; For example:
;
;   extension=mysqli
;
; When the extension library to load is not located in the default extension
; directory, You may specify an absolute path to the library file:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
;
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
;
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap
extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-persistent
mysqli.max_persistent = -1

; Allow accessing, from PHP's perspective, local files with LOAD DATA statements
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow_local_infile
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/mysqli.allow-persistent
mysqli.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/mysqli.max-links
mysqli.max_links = -1

; Default port number for mysqli_connect().  If unset, mysqli_connect() will use
; the $MYSQL_TCP_PORT or the mysql-tcp entry in /etc/services or the
; compile-time value defined MYSQL_PORT (in that order).  Win32 will only look
; at MYSQL_PORT.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-port
mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-socket
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-host
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-user
mysqli.default_user =

; Default password for mysqli_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
; Note that this is generally a *bad* idea to store passwords in this file.
; *Any* user with PHP access can run 'echo get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")
; and reveal this password!  And of course, any users with read access to this
; file will be able to reveal the password as well.
; http://php.net/mysqli.default-pw
mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
; Enable / Disable collection of general statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On

; Enable / Disable collection of memory usage statistics by mysqlnd which can be
; used to tune and monitor MySQL operations.
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

; Records communication from all extensions using mysqlnd to the specified log
; file.
; http://php.net/mysqlnd.debug
;mysqlnd.debug =

; Defines which queries will be logged.
;mysqlnd.log_mask = 0

; Default size of the mysqlnd memory pool, which is used by result sets.
;mysqlnd.mempool_default_size = 16000

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used when sending commands to MySQL in bytes.
;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048

; Size of a pre-allocated buffer used for reading data sent by the server in
; bytes.
;mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size = 32768

; Timeout for network requests in seconds.
;mysqlnd.net_read_timeout = 31536000

; SHA-256 Authentication Plugin related. File with the MySQL server public RSA
; key.
;mysqlnd.sha256_server_public_key =
```

What's weird is that the path seems to be pointing to the right directory and file but the PHP console is telling me it cannot find the DLL file.
[The target path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRsXV.png)
[What the console is telling me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7R39.png)
I've also tried this .php document and it also says it's not loaded.

```
    <?php if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
?>
```

[What this PHP document is telling me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJYZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

What ended up happening was I installed the x86 version of PHP and successfully enabled the module. I still don't have a clue why the x64 version of PHP didn't want to cooperate though. Anyhow, problem fixed, yay!

Answer (score 0):

I use windows10 and found the same problem as you.

I try to put this line in php.ini file
Then it's work with me. You can change the path to match your local url.

extension_dir = "C:\php7\ext"

Comment: The question does specify Windows 10. Did you read the other answer? It might be a good idea to edit your answer to explain why you think that will solve the problem.

Comment: The extension dir may be different, depending on the specific setup, as PHP is - at least to my knowledge - not yet available as install option of Windows 10 server, and needs to be manually installed.